# Power Automate - split values from array

Tags: arrays, sharepoint, power-automate

I'm building a flow to retrieve from SharePoint the users (emails address) that upload files to the libraries, and them to write those emails on an Excel.

I can get the emails of those users, and the amount of files that they upload (if user A uploads 3 files e get 3 times the user A, that's ok for me)

My problem is that on the Excel output, I get all values on the same cell
[image]

I want to have each email on a different row.

[image]

In the compose action I already try to use the split function but without success

Comment: You need to have a sub loop over the array that you have shown there and write a row for each one.  So nest another loop to achieve that.

Comment: Try and replicate it in Excel directly, I'm pretty sure you can't.  Happy to be proven wrong though.

Comment: Can you share the setup of your Select? My guess is that with some reconfiguration you can solve this in your Select action. It looks like you want to use the Body in the from (which is the array). If you just want to grab the values you can switch the Map field of the Select to text mode (default it is using key/value mode). In the Map field you can also use `item()['User']`, which should give you the User value. After that you can join it all together as a string value with a join function and a separator. `join(body('Select'), ', ')` in the Compose action.